# ArCore + Android NDK + OpenCV. Image from ArFrame to valid cv::Mat

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk, arcore

I'am use ArCore with Android NDK. And I want to recognize square from each frame of ArFrame.

I'am successfully get ArImage throught ArFrame_acquireCameraImage(...) and convert it to AImage throught ArImage_getNdkImage(...).

After, when I do it, I need to create cv::Mat, that use it for processing. 
It is possible to create cv::Mat from AImage?

When I get plane data from AImage throught AImage_getPlaneData(...), may I create a valid cv::Mat from this plane data?

Thanks!